# Are you allowed a lawyer in this situation?

Tags: united-states, interrogation

I saw a video of a police interrogation on Youtube where first the officer reads the detainee his Miranda Rights which includes he had the right to have an attorney present during the interrogation, and he could stop the interview at any point if he didn't want to answer any question

After signing this document the officer further asks him to sign another document that said the detainee voluntarily "waives all those rights" of his own volition, so that the officer can go on with the interview

What I don't understand is, is the detainee no longer allowed legal counsel after this point? Can he still stop the interview at any point if he doesn't like the officer's question?

Answer (score 4):

The detainee can stop the interview at any point and ask for legal council; signing that he has waived those rights *for now* does not amount to a permanent waiver. The purpose of the document is to provide evidence, should it be needed, that, having been advised of their rights, they have chosen to forego them.

Comment: Would it be within the interrogating officer's rights to bully the subject into believing that he no longer had a right to an attorney because he'd signed that away?